# Given an array A[] of N integers and an index Key. Your task is to print the element present at index key in the array

Tags: java

```
public class PresentIndex {
    public static int findElementAtIndex(int arr[], int n, int key){

        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == key)
               return i;
        }
        return -1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        int n = arr.length;
        int key = 2;
        System.out.println("fixed point is:"+findElementAtIndex(arr,n,key));

    }
}
```

am not able to print the index values

Comment: it is always returning -1 , i want values to return i,
can anyone help me on this

Comment: `int key = 2;` - yes this value is not in your array.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: you are looking for an element with value 2, not the index. check i == key, instead of array[i] == key

Comment: *Your task is to print the element present at index key in the array* - so `s.o.p (arr[key]);`

Comment: I honestly don't understand this task. You say "*print the element present at index key in the array*". But isn't this just simply `array[key]`? What's the need for the method then?

Comment: Given an array A[] of N integers and an index Key. Your task is to print the element present at
index key in the array.
Example 1:
Input:
5 2
10 20 30 40 50
Output:
30

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing wrong here is in your IF statement
you are comparing an Index to a value. which in this case thankfully it does not match.

what you really need to do here is compare I to N not arr[i]

in  your case it will iterate like this

```
Is 10 equal to 2
Is 20 equal to 2
Is 30 equal to 2
```

so now you can see why your IF statement does not execute the desired line.
Also I am guessing you are trying to print 30 and not the number of your index

```
public class PresentIndex {
    public static int findElementAtIndex(int arr[], int n, int key){

        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i == key)
               return arr[i];
        }
        return -1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        int n = arr.length;
        int key = 2;
        System.out.println("fixed point is:"+findElementAtIndex(arr,n,key));

    }
}
```

try this out